# Invalid character in the given encoding. line 1, position 1

Tags: c#, powershell

I've searched through stackoverflow for potential solutions to this issue but I can't seem to find anything that matches with my issue.

I keep getting this error :

[image]

This error pops up every time I try to access through my code specific files, for example Files with these paths :

> C:\\Users\\Me\\Libraries_1\\example1.xml

> C:\\Users\\Me\\Libraries_1\\Books_2\\example2.xml

> C:\\Users\Me\\Data\\Note_1\\example1.xml

Whereas these other paths work perfectly

> C:\\Users\\Me\\Libraries\\example1.xml

> C:\\Users\\Me\\Libraries\\Books\\example2.xml

> C:\\Users\\Me\\Data\\Note\\example1.xml

I noticed that the error happens when the path contains an integer right before a "\\".
Now I'm not sure if this is what causes the error but I looked for any other error even in my code but can't find anything.

**Question** :

*- Is there somehow a condition that makes the integer before the '\' to not be detected in the xml encoding ?*

*- Is there any other solution to this issue ?*

**NB**

These paths are used as parameter in a PowerShell function as such

```
shell.AddCommand("Create-Package").AddParameter("Path", $"{Path}").AddParameter("Output", $"{packageOutputDirectory}");
shell.Invoke();
```

The error happens when I execute **shell.invoke()**

Comment: Where and when does the error occur? When you try to build the project in Visual Studio? When you run it? Specifically when `PowerShell.Invoke()` is called?

Comment: It occurs exactly when the PowerShell.Invoke() is called

Comment: As an aside: you don't need `\\ ` in PowerShell strings to represent single backlashes (though it is usually benign); `\ ` has no special meaning in PowerShell.

Comment: The error message implies that there's a problem with the _content_ of your files, which is unrelated to their _path_.

Comment: Can you provide any info about the files themselves? Is there any difference between those in e.g. the Libraries and Libraries_1 folders?